# How do I kill an OpenVPN connection using Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, openvpn

Is there any way to kill an user OpenVPN connection with a Linux or Perl command?

Comment: This question belongs on serverfault

Comment: but by kill command, in programming kill a connection. but how i ask that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for disconnecting a connected user:

```
/usr/bin/openvpn-sudo-user kill \"username\"
```

but first you should disable the user.

Answer (score 1):

system call to the **tcpkill** program.

Answer (score 1):

use `tcpkill ip host 192.168.1.2`

Answer (score 1):

if you launch openvpn as a command with perl module Proc::Background, you can also kill him with same Proc::Background:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Proc::Background;

my $command = 'openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/client.conf';
my $proc = Proc::Background->new($command); $proc->alive;
print "started\n";
sleep (30);
if ($proc->alive == 1) { $proc->die; print "stopped\n";}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting OpenVPN automatically as a service at boot time, the cleanest way would be to do:

```
service openvpn stop
```

from the command line (or exec it from perl)

```
/etc/init.d/openvpn stop
```

You could kill it directly as other suggest, but using the provided method to stop the service will do any addition cleanup that OpenVPN needs (e.g., cleaning up lock files, run pid files, etc.)

AFIAK killing OpenVPN will be fine in the current version, but who knows for a future version.